# puppet "Error 400 on SERVER : Could not find class"

Tags: puppet

There are TOO many post and solution for this problem, but still i am not able to solve it. 
I am using puppet 3.7.5

Following is details

```
root@p1:/etc/puppet/manifests# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40 Apr  9 12:37 nodes.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18 Apr  9 11:58 site.pp
root@p1:/etc/puppet/manifests# cat nodes.pp
node 'wa.ro.XXX' {
        include mytest
}
root@p1:/etc/puppet/manifests# cat site.pp
import 'nodes.pp'
```

Module path

```
root@p1:/etc/puppet/manifests# puppet master --configprint modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

root@p1:/etc/puppet# tree -L 2 -d modules
modules
- configfiles
  -- files
  -- manifests
- services
  -- files
  -- manifests

root@p1:/etc/puppet# cat modules/services/manifests/init.pp
class mytest {
       file { '/tmp/puppettestfgt56666' :
          mode    => 0644,
          content => "This Learning Puppet VM's IP address is ${ipaddress}",
         }        
}
```

On agent

```
root@wa:/var/cache# puppet agent --no-daemonize --onetime --verbose
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class mytest for wa.ro.XXX on node wa.ro.XXX
Notice: Using cached catalog
Info: Applying configuration version '1428561896'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds
```

Comment: Please note that in Puppet `3.7` and above, you should not use `import` at all. Use a setting of `manifest=/etc/puppet/manifests` instead (puppet.conf). While you're at it, see about migrating everything to directory environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `mytest` can and will only be found in module `mytest`. You cannot just throw it into module `services` and expect Puppet to be able to look it up from there.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i have multiple classes in a module.

Comment: @MudasarYasin You can namespace classes, e.g. `site::mytest` will be searched for in the `site` module, either in `site/manifests/mytest.pp` or `site/manifests/init.pp`.

Comment: Thanks......i got answer of my own question.......and thanks you for always help me.....
I define another class  with name services::myfile and call in in its node file.